# Recharts styling with scss

Tags: sass, styling, recharts

I need to remove recharts horizontal grid last line, here is the scss:

```
.hideLastLine {
  .recharts-wrapper {
    .recharts-surface {
      .recharts-cartesian-grid {
        .recharts-cartesian-grid-horizontal {
          line:last-child {
            stroke-opacity: 0 !important;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And applied it to responsive container:

```
 <ResponsiveContainer width={width} height={height} className={styles.hideLastLine}>
      <LineChart data={chartData}>
        <CartesianGrid />
         {...}
      </LineChart>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
```

But my styles don't take effect, any idea why?

Comment: Hello there! Is you might need to share more code or give screenshots of the issue. I am not able to replicate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to use SCSS to hide the last horizontal grid line in a Recharts LineChart component within a ResponsiveContainer. The code you've provided looks correct, so the issue might be related to the specificity of your CSS selector or the order of applying styles. Here are a few things you can check:

**Specificity:** Make sure that your SCSS selector is specific enough to target the last horizontal grid line. Since Recharts generates the SVG elements, using more specific selectors can help ensure that your styles are applied. You might want to increase the specificity like this:

```
.hideLastLine {
  .recharts-wrapper {
    .recharts-surface {
      .recharts-cartesian-grid {
        .recharts-cartesian-grid-horizontal {
          > line:last-child {
            stroke-opacity: 0 !important;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Order of Styles:** Sometimes, the order of stylesheets or the way you're importing them can affect the specificity of selectors. Make sure that the styles are being applied after the Recharts' default styles.

**CSS Modules Naming:** If you're using CSS Modules or similar naming conventions, ensure that the styles.hideLastLine class is indeed being applied to the ResponsiveContainer. You can add a regular CSS class name to your ResponsiveContainer to see if the styles apply as expected.

**Check for Conflicting Styles:** There might be conflicting styles from other parts of your application that are affecting the final appearance. Use browser dev tools to inspect the rendered styles and see if any other styles are overriding your desired changes.

**Version Compatibility:** Make sure that the version of Recharts you're using doesn't introduce any changes that might affect the CSS structure you're targeting.

**Component Structure:** Ensure that the structure of the generated SVG elements matches what you're targeting in your CSS. Sometimes, component updates can alter the generated SVG structure.

**Inspect Rendered HTML:** Use the browser's developer tools to inspect the rendered HTML and the applied styles. This will help you identify if the styles are being applied correctly or if there are any issues with specificity.

If you've tried these steps and the issue still persists, please provide more context or code snippets, especially if there are any additional layers of abstraction or complexity in your codebase that might be affecting the styles.

I am not a professional but hopefully this will help you solve your issues!